# XNA/C#: Entity Factories and typeof(T) performance

Tags: xna, c#

In our game (targeted at mobile) we have a few different entity types and I'm writing a factory/repository to handle instantiation of new entities.  Each concrete entity type has its own factory implementation and these factories are managed by an EntityRepository.

I'd like to implement the repository as such:

```
Repository
{
 private Dictionary <System.Type, IEntityFactory<IEntity>> factoryDict;

 public T CreateEntity<T> (params) where T : IEntity
 {
      return factoryDict[typeof(T)].CreateEntity() as T;
 }
}
```

usage example

```
var enemy = repo.CreateEntity<Enemy>();
```

but I am concerned about performance, specifically related to the typeof(T) operation in the above.  It is my understanding that the compiler would not be able to determine T's type and it will have to be determined at runtime via reflection, is this correct? One alternative is:

```
Repository
{
 private Dictionary <System.Type, IEntityFactory> factoryDict;

 public IEntity CreateEntity (System.Type type, params)
 {
      return factoryDict[type].CreateEntity();
 }
}
```

which will be used as

```
var enemy = (Enemy)repo.CreateEntity(typeof(Enemy), params);
```

in this case whenever typeof() is called, the type is on hand and can be determined by the compiler (right?) and performance should be better.  Will there be a noteable difference?  any other considerations?  I know I can also just have a method such as CreateEnemy in the repository (we only have a few entity types) which would be faster but I would prefer to keep the repository as entity-unaware as possible.

EDIT:

I know that this may most likely not be a bottleneck, my concern is just that it is such a waste to use up time on reflecting when there is a slightly less sugared alternative available. And I think it's an interesting question :)

I did some benchmarking which proved quite interesting (and which seem to confirm my initial suspicions).

Using the performance measurement tool I found at
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2006/09/21/765648.aspx
(which runs a test method several times and displays metrics such as average time etc) I conducted a basic test, testing:

```
private static T GenFunc<T>() where T : class 
    {

        return dict[typeof(T)] as T;
    }
```

against

```
    private static Object ParamFunc(System.Type type)
    {
        var d = dict[type];
        return d;
    }
```

called as

```
str = GenFunc<string>();
```

vs

```
str = (String)ParamFunc(typeof(String));
```

respectively.  Paramfunc shows a remarkable improvement in performance (executes on average in 60-70% the time it takes GenFunc) but the test is quite rudimentary and I might be missing a few things. Specifically how the casting is performed in the generic function.

An interesting aside is that there is little (neglible) performance gained by 'caching' the type in a variable and passing it to ParamFunc vs using typeof() every time.

Comment: perhaps I should post this to a more general programming forum..

Comment: This isn't going to be a bottleneck.

Comment: @Ruan: No doubt Stack Overflow would have given you a near-instantaneous answer - perhaps with even more detail than I gave.

Comment: those tests, in debug or release builds?

Comment: @Raine: And more importantly: without the debugger attached? (Changes the JIT behaviour!)

Comment: Just confirming your result: `ParamFunc` takes about 73% of the time of `GenFunc` using the same test framework.

Comment: Just a note: any decent IoC container (such as [AutoFac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/)) can do this automatically.  If you use one of those, there is no need to write your own repository, or to write your own `CreateEntity()` methods, or even to call the `CreateEntity()` method yourself - the library does all of this for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generics in C# don't use or need reflection.

Internally types are passed around as `RuntimeTypeHandle` values. And the `typeof` operator maps to `Type.GetTypeFromHandle` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.gettypefromhandle.aspx)). Without looking at Rotor or Mono to check, I would expect `GetTypeFromHandle` to be O(1) and very fast (eg: an array lookup).

So in the generic (`<T>`) case you're essentially passing a `RuntimeTypeHandle` into your method and calling `GetTypeFromHandle` *in* your method. In your non-generic case you're calling `GetTypeFromHandle` first and then passing the resultant `Type` into your method. Performance should be near identical - and massively outweighed by other factors, like any places you're allocating memory (eg: if you're using the `params` keyword).

But it's a factory method anyway. Surely it won't be called more than a couple of times per second? Is it even worth optimising?

Comment: thanks for you response... I have edited my question to add in some of my own conclusions following benchmarking

Comment: @Ruan: An important part of optimising is measuring - so good work for doing that. As you discovered, the non-generic method is a tiny bit faster, so you could go with that (although I would *strongly* recommend going with whatever makes your code easiest to read - even if it costs a few micro-seconds). If it were using reflection I would expect it to be orders of magnitude slower, rather than a measly 36%.

Comment: +1, interesting peek into the generic internals. Also good advice in regards of measuring perf before banging your head on the desk.

Comment: Messing about with the IL, the main difference I can see is that the generic version has an additional [`unbox.any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.unbox_any.aspx) instruction following an `isinst`. Whereas the non-generic method uses either a single `castclass` or `isinst` (both perform the same). It might be interesting to see if removing that instruction makes the performance equivalent (and if it breaks anything - I don't really mess about at the IL level often). Otherwise perhaps there is some indirection cost to using the generic type.

Comment: Certain operations on generics will use reflection. For example if you have a `new()` constraint and then create an instance of a reference type using `new T()` it will use reflection.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: It uses `Activator.CreateInstance<T>()`. Does that count as reflection? I'm not so sure it does. I'm pretty sure it doesn't require reflection permission, for starters. Also I'm pretty sure it doesn't suffer from the performance issues associated with reflection. But then, I haven't checked it extensively.

Comment: Also it seems my last comment got lost in the question migration: I later found out that the `unbox.any` instruction is required to make the function verifiable.

Comment: A little bit of research indicates that generic new is something like 10-100 times slower than a non-generic `new` (it's hard to pin down an exact figure). But then `new` itself is very fast. And generic new is still a lot faster than other reflection-based alternatives for `new`.

Answer (score 1):

You always hear how slow reflection is, but in C#, there is actually fast reflection and slow reflection.  [`typeof` is fast-reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163759.aspx) - it has basically the overhead of method call, which is nearly infinitesimal.

I would bet a steak and lobster dinner that this isn't going to be a performance bottleneck in your application, so it's not even worth your (or our) time in trying to optimize it.  It's been said a million times before, but it's worth saying again:  ["Premature optimization is the root of all evil."](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/79946/what-is-the-best-retort-to-premature-optimization-is-the-root-of-all-evil/79995#79995)

So, finish writing the application, *then* profile to determine where your bottlenecks are.  If this turns out to be one of them, then *and only then* spend time optimizing it.  And let me know where you'd like to have dinner.

---

Also, my comment above is worth repeating, so you don't spend any more time reinventing the wheel:  *Any decent IoC container (such as AutoFac) can [create factory methods] automatically. If you use one of those, there is no need to write your own repository, or to write your own `CreateEntity()` methods, or even to call the `CreateEntity()` method yourself - the library does all of this for you.*